# What can the phrase “is embedded in a whale of a bill” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is an excerpt from “Abstinence Or Obstinacy?” (The Washington Post; May 17, 2002):

"Soon after, the measure providing more money for President Bush's cherished abstinence-only program sailed out of the House Energy and Commerce Committee, heading to the floor, where it passed yesterday. No surprise there. The provision to keep America's teenagers as ignorant as possible about sex -- even, as Capps knows, to teach them what is false -- **is embedded in a whale of a bill** that contains so much for so many that, should it have failed, it could only meant that our cherished political system has collapsed and reason has triumphed."

I thought that whales were marine mammals!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Whale" here is a metaphor. A metaphor states that one thing is another thing. It equates those two things not because they actually are the same, but for the sake of comparison or symbolism. A whale is a large marine mammal, and the blue whale is the largest of all marine mammals. Also whales eat smaller creatures. To call something a "whale" of a thing is to employ the word as a metaphor to mean it is very big and, perhaps, capable of devouring or hiding many things.

[What is a metaphor?](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/metaphor/)

[Metaphors relating to animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Metaphors_referring_to_animals)

Comment: Why than say “imbedded in a whale” instead “is a whale of” or “is the whale of”?

Comment: The "provision to keep America's teenagers ignorant about sex" is only one thing hidden or buried ("embedded") in a very large bill (piece of proposed legislation).

Comment: I don't think you need to explain the concept of a metaphor here. It doesn't answer the question, really.

Comment: Please explain your comment.

Comment: I think perhaps the OP is not aware of the "an X of a Y" construction for *using* metaphors, rather than unaware of metaphors in general.

Comment: @Zak A “bill” is a proposed law.    So when the author says something is “embedded in a whale of a bill”: it is something important, but small, and placed in a huge bill with many other things.   A “whale of a bill” means a tremendously huge, long bill.  And the item is hidden somewhere in there.

Comment: @poepje Reading Zaks question and comments, the basic misunderstanding seems to be that this is not about a *literal* whale. Some species of whales do have *beaks,* and "bill" is another name for a bird's beak - but of course the literal meanings don't make much sense, hence the OP's question! If the quote had said "... embedded in a whale-like bill …" it would have been more obvious that "whale" here is being used as an adjective, not a noun.

Comment: I got that... It's just that everyone understands the concept of a metaphor itself, thus it doesn't require explanation.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are parsing the phrase wrong, if you think that something is embedded in a whale.  It should be read as "embedded in (a whale of a bill)".

As Michael Harvey pointed out, "a whale of a X" is a colloquial expression for "a very large X".  So the phrase just says that the provision is embedded in a very large bill.